# use postprocessing effects with threejs with a static background image

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I found a neat code snippet to create volumetric lights inside threejs from Andrew Berg (can be seen here: https://codepen.io/abberg/pen/pbWkjg?editors=0010 ) who utilized post-processing and shaders to create a volumetric ball of light.

My question is how do I modify my code so that I can simultaneously have a static image being rendered in the background while using the composer renderer that will create the volumetric light, because currently I can do one or the other but not both.

If I remove the `render();` call in my animate function and remove the comments from `//renderer.render(backgroundScene,backgroundCamera);
 //renderer.render(scene,camera);`

I am able to see the static background image however the postprocessing effects that make the Volumetric Light won't be used, and vice-versa if I leave the `render();` function and leave those lines commented out I can see the post processing effects and the light ball shader.

**main.js**

```
var scene, camera, renderer,
    testcube, composer;

var backgroundMesh, backgroundScene, backgroundCamera,
    backgroundComposer;

var occlusionComposer, occlusionRenderTarget, 
    occlusionBox, lightSphere, sphereUniforms;

var OCCLUSION_LAYER, DEFAULT_LAYER;

var incr;

function init(){

    incr = 0;
   OCCLUSION_LAYER = 1;
   DEFAULT_LAYER = 0;

   renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false, alpha:true });
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
   renderer.autoClear = false;
   renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);


   scene = new THREE.Scene();

   var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,10,10);
   var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff});
   lightSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo,sphereMat);
   lightSphere.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
   lightSphere.position.z = 0;
   lightSphere.position.y = -150;
   lightSphere.position.x = -150;

   scene.add(lightSphere);

   var boxGeo =  new THREE.BoxGeometry(50,50,50);
   var boxMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffff13});
   testcube = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo,boxMat);

   scene.add(testcube);

   testcube.position.z = 0;
   testcube.position.y = -100;
   testcube.position.x = -90;

   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1,7000);

   camera.position.z = 200;
   camera.position.x = -150;
   camera.position.y = -150;
   scene.add(camera);

   var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
   scene.add(light);

    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

    backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
    backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();
    backgroundScene.add( backgroundCamera );

    loader.load( 'img/background.png', function( texture ) {
        backgroundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: texture
            })
        );

        backgroundMesh.material.depthTest = false;
        backgroundMesh.material.depthWrite = false;
        backgroundScene.add( backgroundMesh );
    });


   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


}
function preprocess(){

    var pass;
    occlusionRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth * 0.5 , window.innerHeight * 0.5 );
    occlusionComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, occlusionRenderTarget);
    occlusionComposer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
    pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.VolumetericLightShader );
    pass.needsSwap = false;
    occlusionComposer.addPass( pass );

    sphereUniforms = pass.uniforms;

    composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
    composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
    pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader );
    pass.uniforms.tAdd.value = occlusionRenderTarget.texture;
    composer.addPass( pass );
    pass.renderToScreen = true;

}
function render(){


    camera.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
    occlusionComposer.render();
    //backgroundComposer.render();
    camera.layers.set(DEFAULT_LAYER);
    composer.render();

}
function animate(){


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.clear();

    render();
    //renderer.render(backgroundScene,backgroundCamera);
    //renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
init();
preprocess();
animate();
```

**shader.js**

```
THREE.VolumetericLightShader = {
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: {value:null},
    lightPosition: {value: new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.5)},
    exposure: {value: 0.18},
    decay: {value: 0.95},
    density: {value: 0.8},
    weight: {value: 0.62},
    samples: {value: 100}
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vUv = uv;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "uniform vec2 lightPosition;",
    "uniform float exposure;",
    "uniform float decay;",
    "uniform float density;",
    "uniform float weight;",
    "uniform int samples;",
    "const int MAX_SAMPLES = 100;",
    "void main()",
    "{",
      "vec2 texCoord = vUv;",
      "vec2 deltaTextCoord = texCoord - lightPosition;",
      "deltaTextCoord *= 1.0 / float(samples) * density;",
      "vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
      "float illuminationDecay = 1.0;",
      "for(int i=0; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++)",
      "{",
        "if(i == samples){",
          "break;",
        "}",
        "texCoord -= deltaTextCoord;",
        "vec4 sample = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
        "sample *= illuminationDecay * weight;",
        "color += sample;",
        "illuminationDecay *= decay;",
      "}",
      "gl_FragColor = color * exposure;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader = {
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: { value:null },
    tAdd: { value:null }
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vUv = uv;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "uniform sampler2D tAdd;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vec4 color = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",
      "vec4 add = texture2D( tAdd, vUv );",
      "gl_FragColor = color + add;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

THREE.PassThroughShader = {
    uniforms: {
        tDiffuse: { value: null }
    },

    vertexShader: [
        "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
          "vUv = uv;",
            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
        "}"
    ].join( "\n" ),

    fragmentShader: [
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
            "gl_FragColor = texture2D( tDiffuse, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y ) );",
        "}"
    ].join( "\n" )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `THREE.Scene` for the background and edit the `background` property of the scene with the background texture:

```
backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();
backgroundScene.add( backgroundCamera );

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
loader.setCrossOrigin("");

var backTexture = loader.load(img/background.png,
    function ( texture ) {
        var img = texture.image;
        bgWidth= img.width;
        bgHeight = img.height;
    }
);
backgroundScene.background = backTexture;
```

Ensure that the `transparent` property of the `THREE.Material` (`material` property) of the final `THREE.ShaderPass` is set `true`:

```
pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader );
pass.uniforms.tAdd.value = occlusionRenderTarget.texture;
composer.addPass( pass );
pass.renderToScreen = true;
pass.material.transparent = true;
```

Finally you have to render the background scene before you render the `THREE.EffectComposer`:

```
renderer.render(backgroundScene,backgroundCamera);

camera.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
occlusionComposer.render();
camera.layers.set(DEFAULT_LAYER);
composer.render();
```

See the Example:

```js
THREE.VolumetericLightShader = {
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: {value:null},
    lightPosition: {value: new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.5)},
    exposure: {value: 0.18},
    decay: {value: 0.95},
    density: {value: 0.8},
    weight: {value: 0.62},
    samples: {value: 100}
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vUv = uv;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "uniform vec2 lightPosition;",
    "uniform float exposure;",
    "uniform float decay;",
    "uniform float density;",
    "uniform float weight;",
    "uniform int samples;",
    "const int MAX_SAMPLES = 100;",
    "void main()",
    "{",
      "vec2 texCoord = vUv;",
      "vec2 deltaTextCoord = texCoord - lightPosition;",
      "deltaTextCoord *= 1.0 / float(samples) * density;",
      "vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
      "float illuminationDecay = 1.0;",
      "for(int i=0; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++)",
      "{",
        "if(i == samples){",
          "break;",
        "}",
        "texCoord -= deltaTextCoord;",
        "vec4 sample = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
        "sample *= illuminationDecay * weight;",
        "color += sample;",
        "illuminationDecay *= decay;",
      "}",
      "gl_FragColor = color * exposure;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader = {
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: { value:null },
    tAdd: { value:null },
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vUv = uv;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "uniform sampler2D tAdd;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vec4 color = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",
      "vec4 add = texture2D( tAdd, vUv );",
      "gl_FragColor = color + add;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

var scene, camera, renderer, composer;
var backgroundScene, backgroundCamera;
var occlusionComposer, occlusionRenderTarget, 
occlusionBox, lightSphere, sphereUniforms;

var OCCLUSION_LAYER, DEFAULT_LAYER;

function init(){

    OCCLUSION_LAYER = 1;
    DEFAULT_LAYER = 0;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false, alpha:true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
    window.onresize = resize;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,10,10);
    var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff});
    lightSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo,sphereMat);
    lightSphere.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
    lightSphere.position.z = 0;
    lightSphere.position.y = -150;
    lightSphere.position.x = -150;
    scene.add(lightSphere);

    var boxGeo =  new THREE.BoxGeometry(50,50,50);
    var boxMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffff13});
    var testcube = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo,boxMat);
    scene.add(testcube);
    testcube.position.z = 0;
    testcube.position.y = -100;
    testcube.position.x = -90;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1,7000);
    camera.position.z = 200;
    camera.position.x = -150;
    camera.position.y = -150;
    scene.add(camera);

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(light);

    backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
    backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();
    backgroundScene.add( backgroundCamera );
    
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    var backTexture = loader.load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/background.jpg",
        function ( texture ) {
            var img = texture.image;
            bgWidth= img.width;
            bgHeight = img.height;
        }
    );
    backgroundScene.background = backTexture;

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function preprocess(){

    occlusionRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth * 0.5 , window.innerHeight * 0.5 );
    occlusionComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, occlusionRenderTarget);
    occlusionComposer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
    var pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.VolumetericLightShader );
    pass.needsSwap = false;
    occlusionComposer.addPass( pass );

    composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
    composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
    pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader );
    pass.uniforms.tAdd.value = occlusionRenderTarget.texture;
    composer.addPass( pass );
    pass.renderToScreen = true;
    pass.material.transparent = true;
}

function render(){
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(backgroundScene,backgroundCamera);
    
    camera.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
    occlusionComposer.render();
    camera.layers.set(DEFAULT_LAYER);
    composer.render();
}

function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

init();
preprocess();
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
```